# All routes with web Middleware return 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In My Laravel application every route written in web middleware return 500 error

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

 // all routes written here return 500  
});

//outside routes works fine
```

*I am using apache2 on Ubuntu

Comment: Have you checked the error log to see what the actual error is?

Comment: Check the error messages and post them to here as @Bogdan said. Also, you should post your "web" middleware.

Comment: I have just checked the log file and it was the .env file hasn't all the info, Thanks for your help :)